# TCP Packet drops on application server

Tags: linux, networking, tcp, zabbix, rhel-7

I have a monitoring application (Zabbix proxy) installed on RHEL 7.8 and since we have a very large environment, we have 2500+ agents connecting to this one server. We're seeing frequent errors while trying to connect to the sever from the agent. The telnet seems to be working but only intermittently.

I increased the net.core.somaxconn limit to the absolute maximum but don't see any notable effect.

I see something like the following on trying to see netstat details.

```
SYN_RECV 168 
CLOSE_WAIT 4 
ESTABLISHED 196 
FIN_WAIT1 3 
TIME_WAIT 1151
```

Also, see the Recv-Q and Send-Q values are either both 128 or recv-q is 129 and the other is 128

```
# ss -ntl '( sport = :10051 )'
State       Recv-Q Send-Q                                     Local Address:Port                                                    Peer Address:Port
LISTEN      129    128                                                    *:10051                                                              *:*
```

I've already tried to modify the following parameters that I've come across while trying to find a solution around the packet drops

```
sysctl -w net.core.somaxconn=65535
sysctl -w net.core.netdev_max_backlog=65535
sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout=15
sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_syn_retries=2
sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_synack_retries=2
sysctl -w net.core.rmem_default=31457280
sysctl -w net.core.rmem_max=12582912
```

But I still see this in netstat -s

```
# netstat -s | grep -i list
    4741435797 times the listen queue of a socket overflowed
    4791100644 SYNs to LISTEN sockets dropped
# netstat -s | grep -i list
    4741436773 times the listen queue of a socket overflowed
    4791101620 SYNs to LISTEN sockets dropped
# netstat -s | grep -i list
    4741438013 times the listen queue of a socket overflowed
    4791102860 SYNs to LISTEN sockets dropped
```

I'm not really a Linux admin and am at my wits end. Any details around how to resolve this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Could you please attach `dmesg` logs? And see if there are any messages about SYN cookies? Do you have any firewall enabled?

Comment: @Fanatique this turned out to be a bug in the code that wasn't using the somaxconn value from the system and was defaulting to128. There's a bug report https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBX-7933 which is now being fixed and should be included in the code soon..

Comment: Interesting! I guess that bug is either in newer versions or I don't hit the limit. I have 400+ agents connecting to the Zabbix 2.4 server, nowhere near 2500 though :D

Answer (score 0):

Quoting https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBX-7933

fix for this - Available in versions:

```
pre-5.0.15rc1 - df1e26d50d
pre-5.4.4rc1 - b8f4af363a
pre-6.0.0alpha1 - 3131b9702a
```

Documentation updated:

```
What' s new in 5.4.4
What' s new in 5.0.15
Process configuration -> Zabbix server in 5.0, 5.4, 6.0
Process configuration -> Zabbix proxy in 5.0, 5.4, 6.0
Process configuration -> Zabbix agent (UNIX) in 5.0, 5.4, 6.0
Process configuration -> Zabbix agent (Windows) in 5.0, 5.4, 6.0
```

(adding this answer only not to have un-answered question popping up :) )